# Como fazer uma tabela responsiva afunilada?

Tags: css, css3, canvas, chart

Estou tentando fazer similar a esta imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[**Aqui um Fiddle até onde consegui fazer**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/7ae52ypf/)

Os dados serão dinâmicos, e preciso que os cantos sejam arredondados.

Aceito outras alternativas ou sugestões para montagem desta tabela.

Comment: Vc quer que a tabela seja responsiva tanto na altura quanto na largura? Em cada uma dessas fileiras pode ter 2 ou 3 ou ate 4 linhas por exemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como vc fez as divisões usando bordas eu não consegui pensar em outra solução que não fosse usando pseudo-elementos e um radial-gradiente...

Segue o exemplo, **deixei um na cor vermelha com transparência para vc ver o alinhamento e como o `radial-gradiente` foi construído**, e o de baixo eu deixei do jeito que deve ser. *Precisei deixar uma faixa de "blur" no gradiente 50% 52% para a renderização ficar um pouco melhor e não ficar um "serrilhado" no circulo.*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o resultado. Deixei o lado da direita para vc mesmo fazer ;) pode ser que vc tenha que fazer um ajuste fino no `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` para ficar perfeitinho no seu gosto...

```css
.funnel_outer {
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding:0 10%;
}
.funnel_outer *{
    box-sizing:border-box}
.funnel_outer ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.funnel_outer ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin:1px 0;
    height: 80px;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    list-style:none
}
.funnel_outer li span{
    border-top-width: 80px;
    border-top-style:  solid;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right:25px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
.funnel_step_1 span{
    width:100%;
    border-top-color: #98c938;
}
.funnel_step_1 span::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -86px;
    left: -26px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at bottom right, red 49%, rgba(255,0,0,0.5) 51%);
}
.funnel_step_2 span{
    width:calc(100% - 50px);
    border-top-color: #729f3b
}
.funnel_step_3 span{
    width:calc(100% - 100px);
    border-top-color: #4b743f
}
.funnel_step_4 span{
    width:calc(100% - 150px);
    border-top-color: #264b44
}
.funnel_step_4 span::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: -10px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at top right, #264b44 50%, #fff 52%);
}

.funnel_outer ul li.not_last span{
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right:5px  solid transparent;
    border-top-width:50px;
}
.funnel_outer ul li span p{
    margin-top: -70px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="funnel_outer">
    <ul>
        <li class="funnel_step_1"><span><p>1</p></span></li>
        <li class="funnel_step_2"><span><p>2</p></span> </li>
        <li class="funnel_step_3"><span><p>3</p></span></li>
        <li class="funnel_step_4"><span><p>4</p></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```